# Has the Halfway Inn outside of Evereska ever been detailed in a published adventure?

Tags: dnd-5e, forgotten-realms, lore, dnd-adventurers-league

The Halfway Inn is described in The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide as being commonly referred to as “Evereska’s Trading Post” straddling the forest and mountains of the elves of Evereska and the edge of the great desert of Anauroch. It serves as a place where traveling merchants often exchange goods. Specially crafted items brought to be traded by elves can also be found.

The Forgotten Realms wiki describes the Halfway Inn [in past tense](http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Halfway_Inn) as if it no longer exists.

This leaves two questions. Does the Halfway Inn still exist in contemporary Adventurers League play? Has any published adventure ever detailed the Inn?

Comment: It's worth noting that everything on the Forgotten Realms wiki is deliberately written in past tense: http://forgottenrealms.wikia.com/wiki/Forum:Past_tense?t=20140115230617

Comment: Thanks Icyfire. That always made me curious. It's an odd style to adopt.

Answer (score 7):

The Sword Coast Adventurer's Guide, page 82, has five paragraphs on The Halfway Inn.

> Does the Halfway Inn still exist in contemporary Adventurers League play?

In the above referenced section, the inn is referred to in the present tense, so presumably it does still exist. Since this exists in official, published 5e materials, it seems reasonable that any Adventurer's League game set in the Forgotten Realms may find itself here.

> Has any published adventure ever detailed the Inn?

I thumbed through the Rise of Tiamat and didn't see any references to the inn. I can't speak to the other published adventures.

Comment: To back this up, a search on D&D Beyond for Halfway Inn with all adventure content unlocked returns no relevant entries, other than the mentioned blurb in SCAG. This does not include any AL-specific modules, though.

Answer (score 2):

Volo's Guide to the Sword Coast (a 2nd edition supplement) has three pages detailing "Places of Interest in the Halfway Inn."

The description includes details such as:

- Paintings on the walls are of magnificent estates and gardens of the nearby, secretive Elven city of Evereska. The paintings are enchanted to glow in low light and cantrips animate the squirrels and some of the people walking in them. They sell for 400-6K gold pieces
- Booths exist in the main hall with heavy curtains for all the trading going on. It is said they are always abuzz with covert meetings, whispered rumors and intrigues
- The door watcher is usually one of the pretty elven barmaids. Behind the desk is a gong to summon guards and a hand crossbow that fires sleep-envenomed darts for troublemakers
- The tavern is run by Myrin Silverspear, discreet, trustworthy old adventurer
- The food is good, cheeses from across the land, nutty robust beer, zzar is an almond-flavored strong sherry strengthened to elven standards